# Run a query each time a database connection is opended Zend FM

Tags: php, zend-framework2, db2, db2-luw

Is it possible to execute a query every time a new connection to the database is open. This query needs to be run immediately after opening a database connection because this query calls a stored procedure that sets up various access control on the tables using the details of the user who requested to run the query. I have tried to call this stored procedure in various places and they are all successful but I would like some feedback.

I have put this query in an abstract mapper class which other mappers extend. Each time a new mapper is instantiated the stored procedure is called.

Another place to put this call to the stored procedure is before calls to other mapper methods. The downside of this is that there will a lot of duplicate code (code that calls the stored procedure).

The final place to put this call is in *Bootstrap.php*. Each *_init* method in this file is suppose to run only once each time the application is loaded. I have decided to put this call to the stored procedure in one of the *Bootstrap.php* for one of our modules. This is so far the best place I can think of because I only have to write the code that calls the stored procedure once and each time the application is accessed the initialize method will run. The downside of this is that I do not know the side affects of putting things in *Bootstrap.php*.

One of the main downsides of all these places is that the stored procedure gets called many times. For the access control to work, the stored procedure needs to be called only once per database session. This will not cause any issue other than speed due to unnecessary calls.

Are there any better places to put this call to the stored procedure? Does Zend FM have this feature implemented somewhere? Is there anything I need to take into consideration if I put this in the *Bootstrap* file.

Thanks for reading this and any help provided.

- DB2 Version 10.5
- Linux Platform
- Zend FM Version 2

Comment: Please specify DB2 version and platform.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can configure this on the database side by setting the [database configuration parameter `connect_proc`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0057371.html) to the name of your stored procedure. Note that the procedure will then be called for all connections, remote and local, including those made by the database administrator.

If you need to pass extra information from the client to the `connect_proc` routine, you could use the [*client accounting string* connection parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0054604.html), which you could then read in the procedure using the [`MON_GET_CONNECTION()` function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053938.html?pos=2):

```
SET acct_string = (
  SELECT client_acctng FROM TABLE (
    MON_GET_CONNECTION(MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE(),-1)
  )
)
```

Comment: The doc says that only procedures with 0 parameters can be used as connect procedure. This won't work because we supply two things to our procedure.